# How to pass library class or objects to fragments?

Tags: android, object, android-fragments, parcelable, serializable

I want to pass a class object to a `Fragment`. I know to pass the class objects then we have to implement serializable or parcelable. But I can not extend or implement compiled libraries or jar files objects to parcelable or serializable. Then how can I pass these type of objects to a `Fragment`?

Example: If I have `Button` class object in one `Fragment` and pass it to another `Fragment`, then how to do this?

Comment: add an example please

Comment: i just answered the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39698275/send-intent-from-main-activity-to-two-fragment

Comment: You can use gson to make class object you want as a string and put to intent,  and deserialiser  that string to object at another activity.

Comment: @Saveen NO your answer is nothing to do with the problem stated here.

Answer (score 2):

That's weird that you want to pass an object of a compiled jar or libraries. But anyway, you might try getting the necessary values from the object you want to pass to another `Fragment`. Then you might create your own class and take an instance of your class to store the values you need there.

Then make the class `Parcelable` which you've created and then pass it to the `Fragment` you want. You'll get plenty of resource about how you can pass objects from one `Fragment` to another.

Hope that helps!